# Information about a State Machine Workflow from inside the workflow

Tags: workflow-foundation, .net-4.5, state-machine-workflow

Is there any API or library to programmatically determine information about a Windows Workflow State Machine Activity from inside the code?

Specifically, is it possible to detect

1.) What state the machine is currently at

2.) What transitions are currently scheduled

3.) What transition executed and led to the entry of a current state?

I'm just getting my feet wet with State Machines in Workflow Foundation (never used them prior to 4.5).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [StateMachine Instance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.workflow.activities.statemachineworkflowinstance.aspx) properties like CurrentState, States, StateHistory and PossibleStateTransitions.

Other useful link [here](http://flylib.com/books/en/1.504.1.66/1/).

Comment: Thanks, but its obsolete API, so I'm trying to avoid.  I ended up going with an external solution using AppFabric

Answer (score 0):

You can implement state machine tracker. Here is the reference:
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Windows-Workflow-fee72008

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, interesting solution.  I was hoping to get this information from inside the workflow.  This solution seems to be more for an external tracker.  Now I'm sure I could wire this up and then have the service call out to something running this, but that seems very messy. Also seems to be more for self-hosted scenarios. I am using .xamlx and AppFabric.  I could inject this using service behaviors, so it could work.